# How to use Enum for singleton?

Tags: java

I have studied the use of Enum to implement Singleton design pattern as Java ensures that any enum value is instantiated only once in a Java program. Since Java Enum values are globally accessible, so is the singleton.

```
class ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization {

    public static ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization instance = new ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization();

    private Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("host", "internal.db");
        put("port", "8179");
        put("user", "admin");
        put("password", "pa$$w0rD");
    }};

    private ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization() {

    }

    public String update(String key, String value) {
        return configMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return configMap.get(key);
    }

    public static ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}

class Scratch_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization configManager =  ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization.getInstance() ;
        System.out.println(configManager.get("password"));


    }
}
```

How can I convert this class into enum singleton?

Comment: Note that in most real-world cases, nothing with state should be a language-level singleton.

Comment: There is no need; your `private` constructor already takes care of this. Making it an enum is externally visible, but it is an implementation detail. Exposing implementation details is a code smell. What you have is better. Of course, as chrylis said: A singleton with state? That's.. suboptimal, whether you do it like this or as an enum.

Comment: @Beginner If you use getInstance method then your static field should be private

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum and add one constructor to translate these predefined values. One example below:-

```
public class Scratch_1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.out.println(ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization.PASSWORD.getValue());
}
}

public enum ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization {
  HOST("internal.db"), PORT("8179"), USER("admin"), PASSWORD("pa$$w0rD");

  private String value;

  ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization(String s) {
     this.value = s;
  }

  public String getValue() {
      return this.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be a good design for the OP (haven’t evaluated). It is not a singleton since you have 4 enum instances.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton implementation using `Enum`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization {
    INSTANCE;

    private static final Map<String, String> CONFIGMAP = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        CONFIGMAP.put("host", "internal.db");
        CONFIGMAP.put("port", "8179");
        CONFIGMAP.put("user", "admin");
        CONFIGMAP.put("password", "pa$$w0rD");
    }

    public String update(String key, String value) {
        return CONFIGMAP.put(key, value);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return CONFIGMAP.get(key);
    }
}
```

Main class implementation:

```
public class Scratch_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization configManager =  ConfigManagerWithEagerInitialization.INSTANCE;
        System.out.println(configManager.get("password"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
pa$$w0rD
```